# Better way to check if a object is present in Django ORM among Get/Filter?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-views

Lets consider I am trying to find if a user with primary key 20 exists or not? I can do this in 2 ways.

The First one :

```
try:
   user = User.objects.get(pk=20)
except User.DoesNotExist:
   handle_non_existent_user()
```

The other way could be :

```
users = User.objects.filter(pk=20)
if not users.exists():
   handle_non_existent_user()
```

Which is better method to do check existence?

This might be related to this : [What is the best way to check if data is present in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025118/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-data-is-present-in-django)
However, people favoured the first method because of specified examples did not had the reference of model queryset.

Also in the answer of following question : [what is the right way to validate if an object exists in a django view without returning 404?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639836/what-is-the-right-way-to-validate-if-an-object-exists-in-a-django-view-without-r)
It is largely based because we are not getting the reference of object in question.

Comment: `exists()` exists for only one reason. Please use it. In some cases, such as when you plan to evaluate the queryset anyways, use `bool(queryset)` instead of `exists()` ([from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** For cases when you almost always sure that the object is db it is better to use `try:get` for cases when there is 50% chance that object doesn't exists then it is better to use `if:filter.exists`

It really depends on code context. For example there are cases when `if` statement is better than `try/except` [Using try vs if in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835756/using-try-vs-if-in-python#1835844)

So for your question it is the same [Difference between Django's filter() and get() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221938/difference-between-djangos-filter-and-get-methods). `get` method underneath calls `filter`

https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/db/models/query.py#L366

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Performs the query and returns a single object matching the given
    keyword arguments.
    """
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.query.can_filter() and not self.query.distinct_fields:
        clone = clone.order_by()
    num = len(clone)
    if num == 1:
        return clone._result_cache[0]
    if not num:
        raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
            "%s matching query does not exist." %
            self.model._meta.object_name
        )
    raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(
        "get() returned more than one %s -- it returned %s!" %
        (self.model._meta.object_name, num)
    )
```

So in case when you use `filter` with `exists`. It will do almost the same code because `exists` underneath does this

```
def exists(self):
    if self._result_cache is None:
        return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
    return bool(self._result_cache)
```

And as you can see `filter.exists` will execute less code and should work faster, but it doesn't return you an object.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the best way in my opinion because if I ever forget to check whether the user exists or not, it will give me an error even if I don't use the `try / except` clause.

Also, `get` was made specifically to get ONE item only.